# How to get Parent Folder path from a relative path

Tags: c#, .net

I have a case there i want to get relative parent folder path from a filepath

string path = @"12345\Service\123\456";
  From this i want get result as ""12345\Service\123"

string path = @"12345\Service\123\456\file.txt";
  From this i want get result as "12345\Service\123\456"

I tried below code get last file/folder from a path
  string lastFolderName = Path.GetFileName(path);

Can anyone suggest a better approach on this

Comment: Why GetFileName? use GetDirectoryName

Comment: I need parent folder path

Comment: If you try with both strings you will notice that you get exactly what you want

Comment: Okay..i will try Path.GetDirectoryName